# JQuery / Select2 width = 100% creates "flashes" on load, how to prevent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a JQuery / Select2 HTML page with quite a few `<option>`s. This works really nicely.

**However** initially for around 0.5-1 second it displays `mySelectBox` and `mySelectBox2` after each other before the reformatting to width=100% kicks in. So that is the time it need to initalize/parse. So this is causing a 'flashing' UI.

How can I prevent this?

```
<label ..> 
   <select id="mySelectBox"> 
     ...
   </select>
</label>
<label>
   <select id="mySelectBox2">  
   </select>
</label>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelectBox').select2({width: '100%'"});
    $('#mySelectBox2').select2({width: '100%'"});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a [Flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), or FOUC for short, and occurs because JS has to wait for the DOM to load before interacting with it. That slight loading delay causes the flash you describe.

To fix this use CSS to set the widths of those elements instead. This works as CSS is applied as the elements are created in the DOM without a delay.

```css
#mySelectBox,
#mySelectBox2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also note that you could use a common class on both those elements to make the selector more simple and maintenance easier should you need to add any further `select` elements in the future.

Comment: Thanks that did work. Do you maybe also know why I see very shortly the old traditional HTML Select scrollbar? See question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508688/select2-shows-flashing-multiple-scrollbar-until-ready

Comment: No problem, glad to help. That scroll bar is the same issue. It's coming from the scrollbar on the `select` element before it's replaced by the elements generated by Select2.