# Select2 shows flashing 'multiple' scrollbar until ready()

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I use a `multiple` select2 element, it very short show a vertical scrollbar (HTML Select) until the `ready()` is called and the element is changed.

This can even be observed at the website https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage. If you scroll to the multiple-combobox, and hit Refresh you very shortly see the traditional scrollbar on the right.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the default `select` element is overflowed. This is why you see the scrollbar on it for a fraction of a second before the Select2 plugin loads and injects the new elements.

To fix this you can add a `overflow: hidden` CSS rule to the `select` elements which you instantiate Select2 on, so that this scrollbar is never shown, no matter how briefly. Note that this will render the `select` element unusable if Select2 fails to load, though.

Comment: Is this better than `visibility: hidden;` ?

Comment: That's an alternative. I didn't suggest it as I wasn't sure how Select2 would handle replacing an element which wasn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: add `visibility: hidden;` to the `<select>`style/CSS.